# HTC One Deactivate Autocorrection

Tags: keyboard, htc-one, auto-correct

Is it possible to deactivate the autocorrection feature of the **HTC One** (Android 4.3) without losing the 'swype' feature of the keyboard?

I could only figure out how to deactivate the 'swype'-, wordprediction and autocorrection feature all together.

What I would like is to deactivate just the behaviour that unknown or uncommon words get corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Settings/Language & Input.  Under "Keyboard & Input Methods" hit the settings icon next to your keyboard.  Scroll down to "Text Correction" hit "Auto Correction" and select "Off". That should do the trick.